# How to insert a blank line after each group?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have the spreadsheet below.  Note that there are cities (usually taking up 3 to 5 rows).  I'd like to  insert a blank line after each group of cities.  So for instance, I'd like to have the following:

```
AkronOH
AkronOH
AkronOH

AlbanyGA
AlbanyGA
etc...
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish it?  (e.g. easier than doing it manually).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Subtotal on ServerName, Filter on Subtotal rows (eg Text Filters, Contains 'Count') and hit `Del`. Subtotal again with Remove All.